# $n \in \mathbb{N^+}$ then $\lim\limits_{n\to \infty}\sqrt[n]{n}=?$

Tags: calculus, limits

My solution like this:

Let $\sqrt[n]n-1=\alpha_n$

$\sqrt[n]n\geq1$  so $\alpha_n\geq 0$

For $n\geq2 $

$$n=(1+\alpha_n)^n=1+n\cdot \alpha_n+\frac{n\cdot (n-1)}{2}\cdot\alpha _n^2+\ldots+\alpha _n^n\geq \frac{n\cdot (n-1)}{2}\cdot\alpha _n^2$$

For $n\geq2 $

$n-1\geq \frac{n}{2}$  then $n\geq \dfrac{n^2\cdot\alpha _n^2}{4}$ so that $0\le \alpha_n\leq \dfrac{2}{\sqrt n}$  and $$\lim\limits_{n\to \infty}\alpha_n=0$$

Finally $$\lim\limits_{n\to \infty}\sqrt[n]{n}=\lim\limits_{n\to \infty}(1+\alpha_n)=1$$

Are there any other solutions?

Comment: A little too tired to check your work on this, but a quick alternative solution is to use L'Hopital's rule to show that $\log(n^{1/n})=\frac{\log(n)}{n}$ converges to $0$, hence the original sequence converges to $e^0=1$.

Comment: @MW: that would be a circular argument. No need to define  exponential function and then logarithmic function at this point.

Comment: Thank you Mittens.

Comment: The notation $\mathbb N^+$ is redundant as all the elements of $\mathbb N$ are positive.

Answer (score 3):

By Taylor's theorem,
$$n^{1/n}=\exp\left(\frac{1}{n}\ln n\right)=1+\frac{\ln n}{n}+O\left(1/n^2\right)$$
as $n\to\infty$. The limit is $1$.

Comment: But  $n \in \mathbb{N^+}$. İn your solutions $n \in \mathbb{R^+}$  Can you use derivative for natural numbers?

Comment: The Maclaurin series for $e^x$ is defined for all $x\in\mathbb{C}$, which also includes natural numbers. So as far as I can tell, there should be no problem.

Comment: Thank you, but is there a solution in $\mathbb{N^+}$